# TwitterKit: Manually create a TWTRSession

Tags: twitter

Is there anyway we can manually log user in and create a TWTRSession to be continued using with TwitterKit? I have tried:

```
NSDictionary *twSessionInfo = [self.accountHelper getTwitterCredential];
TWTRSession *twSession = [[TWTRSession alloc] initWithSessionDictionary:twSessionInfo];
[TwitterKit setValue:twSession forKey:@"_session"];
```

but Twitter class doesn't have `_session` property.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Default Login

In general, the easiest way to login with Twitter is to use the standard:

```objc
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Session: %@", session);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

### Custom Login

However, if you would really like to use your own login information (say your app had already been using a custom Twitter login and you want to migrate to TwitterKit), then you can do something like this:

```objc
TWTRSession *session = [[TWTRSession alloc] initWithAuthToken:@"cwimJSZ3Hatv1" authTokenSecret:@"HdDFPKWPwLj49DH4p4kNz9cX2" userName:@"TestUser323" userID:@"8723892340"];

[[Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore saveSession:session completion:^(id<TWTRAuthSession> session, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Session: %@", session);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would give it a try